# Creating Linked List gives Segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

The following code is for creating a Singly Linked List and display it using two functions **create_ll()**  and **display()**.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node
        {
            int data;
            struct Node* next;

        };

struct Node* create_ll(struct Node*);
struct Node* display(struct Node*);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct Node* start=NULL;
    int option=0;
    do 
    {
        printf("\t\t\t*******MAIN MENU********");
        printf("\n\t1.Create a list");
        printf("\n\t2.Display the list");
        printf("\n\t3.Exit");
        scanf("%d",&option);
        switch(option)
        {
            case 1: start=create_ll(start);
                printf("\nLinked list created");
                break;
            case 2: start=display(start);
                break;
        };
    }while(option!=3);

    return 0;

}
struct Node* create_ll(struct Node* start)
{
    struct Node *new_node,*ptr;
    int num;
    printf("Enter -1 to end");
    printf("\nEnter data");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    while(num!=-1)
    {
        printf("Creating Node....");
        new_node=(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

        if(new_node!=NULL)
        {
            new_node->data=num;
            if (start==NULL)
            {
                new_node->next=NULL;
                start=new_node;
            }
            else
            {
                ptr=start;
                while(ptr->next!=NULL)
                    ptr=ptr->next;
                ptr->next=new_node;
                new_node->next=NULL;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nOut of Memory!");
        }
        printf("\nEnter data");
        scanf("%d",&num);
    }
    return start;
}
struct Node* display(struct Node* start)
{
    struct Node *ptr;
    ptr=start;
    while(ptr->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\t",ptr->data);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    return start;
}
```

It compiles successfully on gcc compiler on Ubuntu without any errors. However, after running it gives segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

gdb shows that the fault is on  line 59:-

```
$ gdb -q LS.out
Reading symbols from LS.out...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/arpit/Desktop/Ds/LS.out 
            *******MAIN MENU********
    1.Create a list
    2.Display the list1
Enter -1 to end
Enter data 4

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004007de in create_ll (start=0x0) at LS.c:59
59        while(ptr->next!=NULL)
```

Comment: `if (start=NULL)` should be  `if (start==NULL)`

Comment: Is this your actual code? It doesn't compile at all. (For example, you hve a mix-up between `count` and `option` in `main`, `struct *Node` is a syntax error and you call some functions without proper arguments. )

Comment: @MOehm The new generation of programmers do not write code. They search for code in internet.:)

Comment: Oh, yes, plenty to find there! But the code has so many errors that I can't say with confidence where the supposed segmentation fault occurs. (Also -- why should Ctrl-C / Ctrl-V work only from the browser to the text editor / IDE and noct the other way round?)

Comment: `start=display();` So, there's these things called *parameters*. The `display` function is expecting one: `struct Node* display(struct Node* start)`. Probably should go ahead and provide one.

Comment: The code is still in making so my mistake between the mix up between `count` and `option`.

Comment: The fault was all because of  `if(start=NULL)`. Now it's fixed

Comment: A segmentation fault can only occur when the program executes. You can only execute a program when you have compiled it. The code above doesn't compile, therefore it can't be used to analyse your problem. You are wasting people's time here, because you fail to provide the _actual_ code that exhibits the described behaviour.

Comment: If you think that's "the" problem in this code, you seriously need to crank up your warning levels, because there's [plenty more where that came from](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e0ff51d33192268).

Comment: Sorry! I pasted the wrong code. I have edited it now @MOehm

Comment: @zahlen it's a bit late now - you have already wasted enough effort:(  How do we know that you have not pasted more non-compiling code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo. Change `if (start=NULL)` to `if (start == NULL)`. In C, `=` is the assignment operator and `==` is used to compare.

When you do `if (start=NULL)`, the variable `start` gets assigned to `NULL` and the `if` block is not executed as the assignment expression returns whatever is on the right hand side. After that, your `ptr` becomes `NULL` and then you dereference `ptr` in the `else` block (`while(ptr->next!=NULL)`) which causes the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

In `display()` you are assuming that ptr is not null

```
struct Node* display(struct Node* start)
{
    struct Node *ptr;
    ptr=start;
    while(ptr->next!=NULL)
```

If start is NULL then `NULL->next` will cause problems.

The error you are seeing is because you do the same in the `create_ll()` function.

Comment: It's not like the OP is even providing an argument to that function from the call in `main` in the first place. `start=display();`  Checking for NULL, while good advice, is kind almost an afterthought at that point, as the OP has already shot themselves in the foot.

Comment: i will put it in a `if(ptr!=NULL)` block